# mldivide versus (LU & linsolve)

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

This question might be too broad to be posted here but I'll try to be as specific as possible. If you still consider it to be too broad, I'll simply delete it.

- Have a look at the EDIT in the bottom for my final thoughts on the subject.
- Also have a look at Ander Biguri 's answer if you have access to the parallel computing toolbox and have an NVIDIA GPU.

### My problem :

I'm solving dynamic equations by using a Newmark scheme (2nd order implicit), which involves solving a lot of linear systems of the form `A*x=b` for `x`.

I've already optimized all the code that doesn't involve solving linear systems. As it stands now, the linear systems solving take up to 70% of the calculation time in the process.

I've though using MATLAB's `linsolve`, but my matrix `A` doesn't have any of the properties that could be used as `opts` input for `linsolve`.

### The idea :

As seen in the documentation of `linsolve` :

> If A has the properties in opts, linsolve is faster than mldivide,
>   because linsolve does not perform any tests to verify that A has the
>   specified properties

As far as I know, by using `mldivide`, MATLAB will use LU decomposition as my matrix `A` doens't have any specific property except for being square.

### My question :

So I'm wondering if I'd gain some time by first decomposing `A` using MATLAB's `lu`, and then feed these to linsolve in order to solve `x = U\(L\b)` with `opts` being respectively upper and lower triangular.
That way I'd prevent MATLAB of doing all the properties checking that takes place during the `mldivide` process.

**Note :** I'm absolutely not expecting a huge time gain. But on calculations that take up to a week, even 2% matter..

Now why don't I try this myself you may ask? Well I've got calculations running until tuesday approximatively, and I'd want to ask if someone has already tried this and gained time, getting rid of the overhead due to matrix property checking by mldivide.

### Toy example :

```
A=randn(2500);
% Getting A to be non singular
A=A.'*A;
x_=randn(2500,1);
b=A*x_;
clear x_

% Case 1 : mldivide
tic
for ii=1:100

    x=A\b;

end
out=toc;
disp(['Case 1 time per iteration :' num2str((out)/100)]);

% Case 2 : LU+linsolve

opts1.LT=true;
opts2.UT=true;

tic;
for ii=1:100

    [L,U]=lu(A);

    % It seems that these could be directly replaced by U\(L\b) as mldivide check for triangularity first
    Tmp=linsolve(L,b,opts1);
    x=linsolve(U,Tmp,opts2);

end
out2=toc;

disp(['Case 2 time per iteration :' num2str((out2)/100)]);
```

---

### EDIT

So I just had the possibility to try a few things.

I missed earlier in the documentation of `linsolve` that if you don't specify any `opts` input it will default to using the `LU` solver, which is what I want. Doing a bit of time testing with it (And taking into account @rayryeng 's remark to "`timeit` that bad boy"), it saves around 2~3% of processing time when compared to `mldivide`, as shown below. It's not a huge deal in term of time gain, but it's something non neglictible on calculations that take up to a week.

`timeit` results on a `1626*1626` linear system:

`mldivide` :

```
 t1 =

   0.102149773097083
```

`linsolve` :

```
t2 =

   0.099272037768204
```

**relative :** `0.028171725121151`

Comment: I think that it won't change anythings ! Why ? If you read the mldivide's documentation you can see the flow chart used to determined the solver. In your case mldivide will use the LU solver, so there should be no difference.

Comment: The only difference will be the property checking, which is stated in the linsolve documentation to take some time

Comment: *"As far as I know, by using mldivide, MATLAB will use LU decomposition as my matrix A doens't have any specific property except for being square"*. Check this: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide_full.png

Comment: In my specific problem (tomography) I need to solve 1 (or very few) `Ax=b` problems with massive `A` matrices. What I needed to do was actually code my own GPU based algorithms to do the job, that was the only way of solving it. Note that also `mldivide` is inbuilt gpu accelerated, so you may be able to use that

Answer (score 4):

I know you do not have NVIDIA GPU and parallel computing toolbox, but if you had, this would work:

If you replace the second test in your code by:

```
tic;

for ii=1:10
        A2=gpuArray(A); % so we account for memory management
        b2=gpuArray(b);
      x=A2\b2;
end
out2=toc;
```

My PC says (CPU vs GPU)

```
Case 1 time per iteration :0.011881
Case 2 time per iteration :0.0052003
```

Comment: I'm not accepting this answer as I need a CPU solution. Although it will definitely help those who can do GPU computations!

Comment: Anders showing off the power of his Tesla :D, it took my Quad-i7 8 seconds on average per iteration.

Comment: @rayryeng just copyed OPs code, but you are rigth. Still, the point was: GPUs are faster :D